# Can the new Affinity Photo app work with multiple images, like Apple Aperture did?

Tags: software, apple-aperture, affinity-photo

I deal with hundreds if not thousands of images a day.  I use Apple's Aperture program because i can edit many images at a time, and copy metadata from one image to the next.  Has anyone used the new Affinity program for Mac yet, and if so is it like Aperture, or can you only deal with one image at a time?

Answer (score 1):

Affinity Photo is much more powerful than Apple's Aperture but its designed to work on a single photo at a time.

It is a very, very nice piece of software though. They're "Developer Module" (meaning Photo Developing) is fantastic design and usability for photographers.

They have a Trial Period, you could give that a shot. But if you're looking for Bulk than I don't think it'll be what you're after. Photoshop with the use of Actions and Droplets would be better. Lightroom of course is a very popular solution as well.

If you're considering Affinity because you don't like the idea of subscription than you might also look at [CaptureOne](https://www.phaseone.com/en/Products/Software/Capture-One-Pro/Highlights.aspx). It's far more powerful than Aperture or Lightroom and is designed for cataloging and bulk work. It is more expensive but its a one time fee and widely considered the best there is for cataloging and bulk editing. There's a trial version of it as well.

Comment: Lightroom is available for a one off purchase, you know...

Comment: They might be working on a Lightroom/Aperture equivalent. I saw it mentioned somewhere on their forum but unfortunately I can't find the reference right now.

Comment: @Jeremy You might be thinking of On1. CaptureOne is already a LR/Aperture equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelClark he was referring to Serif making a Cataloging Software which he's correct on. Well as a possibility but its deep in their timeline if they are doing it - https://affinity.serif.com/forum/index.php?/topic/19476-affinity-lightroom/

Comment: @RyanFromGDSE, well sniped :-P you are mostly correct. I was thinking of a mix of that and the other program they're working on called Affinity Designer but I had seen the cataloging software mentioned as well so I mixed them up. Thanks for the forum link. Here is another related link. https://affinity.serif.com/en-us/about/

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Desktop version allows batch editing and macro recording meaning you can edit more than one photo at a time.  I use it for resizing a whole directory of images so I can post them on line at a more reasonable size.  I also used it once to change the white balance of a whole group of pics when I left my camera on its Tungsten setting.

I don't know if the Apple version has the same features but I would imagine it would because the Apple version was developed before the Windows version.

Comment: The question is about specific specific software, not about automation on OS level