# Can't view just one photo in Affinity when more than one is loaded

Tags: troubleshooting, affinity-photo

When loading more than one photo in Affinity I get 1/4 of one on top of another photo.
I have to stop Affinity and then quit Affinity to load another photo.
Is there a way I can load more than one photo and select which one I want to work on?

Mac 10.13.2

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see from quickly looking at their website it is more of a photoshop like program and not for cataloging/editing multiple photos.

Check out this question for some alternatives:
[Can the new Affinity Photo app work with multiple images, like Apple Aperture did?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/83871/can-the-new-affinity-photo-app-work-with-multiple-images-like-apple-aperture-di)